# Digital Ocean Returns "message": "no Route matched with those values"

Tags: laravel, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm following this `https://gist.github.com/vicgonvt/cd0431a5cdc043ebab7f4954f7b4d471`

Then when im trying to access my site.

```
{
"message": "no Route matched with those values"
}
```

Im testing all the routes but the result is the same. Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Share your accessed url, route and controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a nginx error. For got to add `public` on root path